# How to make a form field readonly using ui-components?

Tags: magento2, adminform, uicomponent

I have this ui-component definition of a form field In my Magento 2 module.

```
    <field name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Some Label</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">something_here</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enter something here</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

and I'm trying to make it readonly. Not disabled. Just readonly.
I tried adding:

```
<item name="readonly" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

to the config section, but obviously I failed.
How can I make the field readonly? Can I make the field readonly?

Comment: What a difference between parameters "disabled" and "readonly"? In my opinion both parameters works in a similar way.

Comment: From what I know, disabled means the field is not sent via post and readonly is sent. My plan is to modify the value of the readonly field via some javascript.

Comment: Sure, but in regular magento form (not ui) the "readonly" attribute means the html-attribute "disabled". In other way you should use a custom component or a custom script, becouse the "readonly" attribute nonexists for the ui-components.

Comment: I'm just going to stick with your answer now. I just hope I don't actually need to make a field disabled in the future.

Comment: Leave formElement as input and add text elementTmpl like this <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/text</item> Refer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/296735/14271

Comment: how to make it dynamic on add action only

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to add the `disabled` parameter to the element like this:

```
<field name="is_active">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Status</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">vendor_rules_rule_form.vendor_rules_rule_form_data_source.is_active</item>
            <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
            <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            </item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">12</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Result should be similar with the `readonly` parameter for the regular form element:

[image: result]

Comment: I'm puzzled here. it works, but it looks wrong to me. If the field is disabled how come is still sent via POST? Anyway, this is a different question. I'll take this for granted for now.

Comment: @Marius This is most likely because when a form is submitted from the backend, it's not the actual form that is submitted but a new form with hidden fields that is created when you click save. The form is created according to the fields in your UI Components XML-file and fields that are marked with `data-form-part`. Take a look at `module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/form.js::initConfig()`, `validate()` and `submit()`. Also look at `lib/mage/utils/misc.js::submit()`. These combined add a new form at the end of the body that is actually submitted.

Comment: @GielBerkers. I've done some research after asking this question and I came to the same conclusion as you explained. You are right. The submitted data does not come from a form.

Comment: I also have to same like issue.. I want to enable price field for configurable product.. Here I have explained [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171452/magento-2-edit-price-field-in-configurable-product-in-admin-panel)

Comment: @Marius, How to make field `disabled` only in edit form not in new form?

Comment: @Marius, How to make field disabled only in edit form not in new form?

Comment: when u dable a feild u cannot read data from it.... so i don't think its readonly

Comment: how to make it dynamic on add action only

Answer (score 5):

For new version of Magento, you need to use `<disabled>true</disabled>` instead of `<item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

In fact, we don't use `<item>` in `<field>` anymore.

Ex:

```
<field name="sales_id" sortOrder="90" formElement="input">
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Sales ID</label>
        <dataScope>sales_id</dataScope>
        <disabled>true</disabled>
    </settings>
</field>
```

Comment: good point, but one remark...you don't "need" to use this approach. It is "recommended" to use that. The old way of doing it still works.

Comment: @Marius yes, this is for someone who looking for the new recommended version, which isn't use `<item>`.