# Magento 2 edit price field in configurable product in admin panel

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, adminform

In magento 2 admin, when we edit product page. Product price field is read only for configurable product.

So that Admin can't change product price for configurable product.

I want to make change so that admin can change product price from admin for configurable product.

[image]

I have created module **Mymodule_ConfigurablePrice**.
So, I created **product_form.xml** file at ***app/code/Mymodule/ConfigurablePrice/view/adminhtml/ui_component*** directory.

code in product_form.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product-details">
        <field name="price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Questions:

- fieldset name is correct? if not, please suggest.
- code for xml is correct? if not, please suggest.
- Else please suggest best way to
  achieve this.

Comment: What is your purpose of assigning configurable product price? Each configurable product's child product has their own attributes (price, quantity, etc.), that child product attributes are used in quote, order, etc.

Comment: Currently as a magento default.
It is showing lowest price of simple product of Configurable product price on list page.
I want ot change it so it will display whatever admin entered in configurable product.

Configurable product => $12.....
(1). Simple Product 1=> $12......
(2). Simple Product 2=> $10......
(3). Simple Product 3=> $14......

Now it will display price $10 on listing page.

I want it so it will display $12(Whatever entered from configurable product).

I had a log customization and based on that this is my requirement to display custom added price on front-end.

Comment: @GopalKacha Did you get the solution? or the full module? Please share.. I am stuck in the same problem

Comment: Yes, I have created module.. I will share with you.

Comment: I have solved this issue by creating plugin method of Magento2. You can get complete detail of the module at:  http://kachagopal.blogspot.com/2018/08/enable-price-field-of-configurable.html

Comment: I tried in Magetno 2.3 but not working. Can you check in Magento 2.3 Version??

Answer (score 2):

**SIMPLE WAY OF CHANGE ANY CONFIGURABLE PRODUCT PRICE IN MAGENTO 2 CE & EE**

There is a simple way change configurable product price after created product and assign its simple products.

1. firstly require to unassigned all simple products of configurable product and change price according to your choice.
2. After change the price successfully and now assign its simple product and save it. you find change in your configurable prodot.

   I simple way work for me with testing another way i have not find on google.

All The Best.

Comment: I have solved this issue by creating plugin method of Magento2.
You can get complete detail of the module at: 
http://kachagopal.blogspot.com/2018/08/enable-price-field-of-configurable.html

Comment: @GopalKacha then I assume if the price of the simple products change, the admin then have to change the price of the configurable product manually?

Answer (score 0):

My solution rewrite Magento/ConfigurableProduct/js/components/price-configurable.js file in funtion handlePriceValue

```
handlePriceValue: function (isConfigurable) {
            this.disabled(!!this.isUseDefault() || isConfigurable);

            if (isConfigurable) {
                this.clear();
            }
        }
```

change into

```
handlePriceValue: function (isConfigurable) {
            /*this.disabled(!!this.isUseDefault() || isConfigurable);

            if (isConfigurable) {
                this.clear();
            }*/
        }
```

1- Create file requirejs-config.js in vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/components/price-configurable": "Vendor_Module/js/components/price-configurable",
        }
    }
}
```

2- Vendor/Module/js/components/price-configurable.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
], function (_, registry, Abstract) {
    'use strict';

    return Abstract.extend({
        defaults: {
            imports: {
                isConfigurable: '!ns = ${ $.ns }, index = configurable-matrix:isEmpty'
            },
            modules: {
                createConfigurableButton: '${$.createConfigurableButton}'
            }
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // resolve initial disable state
            this.handlePriceValue(this.isConfigurable);
            // add listener to track "configurable" type
            this.setListeners({
                isConfigurable: 'handlePriceValue'
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Calls 'initObservable' of parent
         *
         * @returns {Object} Chainable.
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe(['content']);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Disable and clear price if product type changed to configurable
         *
         * @param {String} isConfigurable
         */
        handlePriceValue: function (isConfigurable) {
            /*this.disabled(!!this.isUseDefault() || isConfigurable);

            if (isConfigurable) {
                this.clear();
            }*/
        }
    });
});
```