# non editable form field in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I need to display a non-editable field in Magento 2.1 Admin grid. so i tried to use :

```
        <field name="type">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">type</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">label</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Order</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">type</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

but i'm getting the following error:

**a:4:{i:0;s:94:"The requested component ("label") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.";i:1;s:7394:"#0 /var/www/magento /vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Provider\Component\Definition->getComponentData('label')**

note: i'm aware about :

```
<item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

but this will just show an inout field as disabled , where i want to show a plain text

any advice?

reference:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2335247d4ae2dc1e0728ee73022b0a244ccd7f4c/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Form/Element/Label.php

Comment: did you managed to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Leave formElement as input and add text elementTmpl `<item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/text</item>`
For that case it'll be something like this

```
<field name="type">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">type</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Order</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/text</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">type</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Know it's a bit too late answer but hope someone will find it usefull